# Choosing a framework - important criteria from UX point of view

Tags: programming

We are starting a new project, and have to decide which framework to take. 
Which criteria are important from the UX point of view?

Comment: I think this is very subjective and influenced by many thing like the business process en personal preferences. But to answer your question as good as I can. UX asks for a lot of testing and trying so choosing a framework with which you can prototype pretty fast, seems logic

Comment: What framework are you talking about?  Is this a web application?  Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of frameworks tend to have UX features built in that help you from having to build them, test them, etc.

If you look at frameworks like Bootstrap they help you achieve at the very least responsive design. But as an added bonus you also get form editing features, menus, modals / dialogs, etc.

The idea behind these frameworks is that it provides developers with a common framework for them to work on and get help if they run into problems. Also helping you get to market faster. Generally speaking though, the UI is something you will want to work on as they don't often have the prettiest UI or a UI that is best suited for your product.

First and foremost is that you must know what you want for your product. Then you will know what should look for. Whether the framework has UI / UX elements that you know you will want and need. Look to see if editing is easy and what the possibilities are.

Answer (score 1):

From a UX perspective, it shouldn't matter. At all.

What matters is who's developing it. If the team that is developing it has the will/skills to built it to meet the UX requirements of the project, you're good to go. Any product/framework should work.

If, on the other hand, the dev team is highly dependent on the framework to be able to produce a UI, then it does make sense to try and find a framework that, out of the box, best matches your needs from a UX POV.

In that situation, it then depends on the type of UX you are after. Quickly built responsive site? Go with Bootstrap. Custom blog? Maybe WordPress. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

UI Frameworks and UX are independent factors. You don't have to mold your UX to fit a framework and there is no unicorn framework that fits every UX design.

Some criteria you can consider are:

1. Responsive design
2. Grid size (960px or 1200px, column count, gutter etc)
3. Mobile first or Desktop first
4. Organic animations vs. static UI

Again, they are not important - but it will help you narrow down a framework that suits your developers for your designated UX.